# SQL query to get department with startdate and enddate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I Have table empDept with the folowing data:

```
EmployeeID Dept  StartDate      EndDate
JON001     PP    15-JUN-2013   13-AUG-2013
JON001     AA    14-AUG-2013   NULL
```

And I have Order Table

```
OrderID TransactionDate EmployeeID
2323     2-JUN-2012     JON001
2324     23-JUN-2013    JON001
2325     2-AUG-2014     JON001
```

And I would like to join the two table to get the following

```
OrderID TransactionDate EmployeeID DEPT
2323     2-JUN-2012     JON001     PP
2324     23-JUN-2013    JON001     PP
2325     2-AUG-2014     JON001     AA
```

Notice orderid 2323 transaction date is less than the min startdate
and Current dept of JON001 does not  have an endDate.
Basically if transaction date is less than min startdate then the min startdate should be open.

How to do the above?

This is what I have so far, But I get  NULL for OrderID 2323 since the transaction date is not between startdate and enddate.

```
  SELECT OT.OrderID
    ,OT.TransactionDate
    ,OT.EmployeeID
    , (
        SELECT TOP 1 Dept FROM EmpDept ED WHERE ED.EmployeeID=OT.employeeID 
        AND OT.trans_date BETWEEN ED.StartDate AND 
        CASE 
          WHEN isnull(ED.EndDate,0)=0 THEN dateadd(year,50,ED.StartDate) 
        END 
    ) "Dept"
    FROM OrderTable OT
```

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: I get NULL Dept for OrderID 2323 since the transaction date is not between startdate and enddate.

Comment: What would you expect to get?  There is no valid department on that date.

Comment: yea. sorry I edit the question if the transaction date is less than min startdate then min startdate can be open (or pick the min startdate as the dept)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
SELECT OT.*
     (SELECT TOP 1 Dept
      FROM EmpDept ED
      WHERE ED.EmployeeID = OT.employeeID
      ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ED.StartDate <= OT.transDate THEN ED.StartDate END) DESC,
               ED.StartDate ASC
     ) Dept
FROM OrderTable OT;
```

You can also express this using `CROSS APPLY`, but a correlated subquery is fine.

Comment: I am not really sure how this works but it is. Does this query ignore DESC if ED.StartDate is bigger than OT.TransDate?

Comment: @BobNoobGuy . . . If no rows match the first condition, then all are given the same value (`NULL`) for the sort order.  The second condition is then used for the sort.